# Hotkey for Zonet KVM3322

Tags: keyboard-video-mouse

I got a second hand Zonet KVM3322 (USB switcher). There's supposed to be a keyboard hotkey combination that can be used to switch between the two attached computers (instead of manually click on the appropriate button on the device). I cannot find the manual online that would tell me what the hotkey combination is.

Comment: Have you tried the "default" ones?
`Scroll lock` is one, `ctrl` is another. Both of them requires double tap, eventually combined with a press on either of the arrows.

Comment: Double Scroll Lock did the trick! I'd be happy to accept your answer if you want to write it up as an answer rather than a comment. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default button for many KVM switches is double tap `scroll lock`

An alternative can be double tap `ctrl`, but I haven't seen that been used that many places.